# flask render_template doesn't work on AJAX post

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, flask

I have a site that makes an AJAX post to a Flask route.

I know there are many similar questions (please don't mark as duplicate) that use the AJAX success method to handle the response. That would work in my simplified example, but the route in my actual code is pulling a bunch of data from a database that gets rendered to multiple tables. I'd prefer not to rewrite all the table data updates in JavaScript, so I really just need to re-render the template.

python:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def hello_world(message=None):
    return render_template('test.html', message=message)


app.run()
```

html

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#mybutton').click(function () {

                $.post(window.location.href, {'test': 'test'});

            });
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
{{ message }}
<button id="mybutton" name="mybutton" type="button">Click Me!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you send `POST` request through AJAX, the request comes from javascript and response data from flask will be stored in a Javascript object. The browser itself doesn't directly send or receive anything, so it won't re-render the page.

You need to define another endpoint in your Flask app to return json data for your POST request, and use AJAX to manipulate the DOM using the returned json data.

Comment: so essentially no way to make this happen?

Comment: so the post is submitting data that is getting inserted into a database. I would like to save the results of inserting (successful or not) and display to the user. I can reload the template with `posting.done(function( ) {window.location.replace(window.location.href);});`, but what would be the way to store the success stuff as that would get cleared on the reload?

Comment: Not sure about the cleared stuff, the question is not clear for me. About reloading the template by replacing `window.location`, doesn't that mean you force the browser to reload the page, so that defeats the purpose of not to rewrite all data?

Comment: Yes it does reload the page. That is the desired state. I wanted the page reloaded because I have written the code already that populates the tables in that manner. It's python based code. If I did it with success on AJAX, I would have to write all that in Javascript.

Comment: I mean if you do that, the browser will send another request, and your backend will have to render and return the template one more time, so it's not really different from putting the posting part into a pure html form without javascript. If you want to use javascript, I don't see any more efficient solution other than sending/receiving minimal data and then manipulating the DOM. I can guarantee what you want to do is possible using jquery or any modern JS frameworks.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't using html forms because my data comes from a number of tables and is stored as JSON so I wasn't sure how to do it. But i think using AJAX then Jquery to reload the tables data is the way to go. I just need to learn how to do it :)

Answer (score 5):

I've looked for the answer to this question on many pages and none of them worked until I found the one that releases the AJAX call so that the rerender is allowed to take place:

```
$('form').on('submit', function(event) {
   $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url:  "{{ url_for( 'myServerFunction' ) }}",
      data: JSON.stringify({'myId':bunchOfIds}),
      contentType: "application/json",
      success:function(response){ document.write(response); }       
   })
```

The most important line is the **success** line that releases the document so that it can be rerendered.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, why don't you just send a 'yes or no' flag from your flask app. Since you want to show the success or failure message without page refresh, getting jquery to update the DOM when your flask app returns a result. Something like
`return message` in your flask app might do the trick accompained by
`success: function(e)({ $('body').append(e);});`. Can't produce more code due to word length restriction on my phone, but tweaking your code along mine gets the job done. Cheers!