# Flask Redirect only works upon refreshing page

Tags: python, flask

flask redirect is not redirecting to the new page. In my index function, upon logging in the redirect does not redirect to the user's homepage; however, it does redirect to the user's homepage upon refreshing the page and checking current_user.authenticated. I have the same exact redirect code in both if statements. Why is it not redirecting right after I login the user?

```
@login.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    user = User()
    username = user.get_username(str(user_id))
    user = User(username = username, id = user_id)
    return user

@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        print('this redirect works')
        return redirect(url_for('home', username = str(current_user.username))) 
    else:
        username = str(request.form.get('user'))
        password = str(request.form.get('password'))       
        user = User(username = username)
        my_hash = user.get_password(username)
        if user.check_password(my_hash, password):
            my_id = user.get_user_id(username)
            user = User(username = username, id = my_id)
            login_user(user, remember=True)
            print('this redirect doesnt work')
            return redirect(url_for('home', username = str(current_user.username))) 
     return render_template('index.html')

@app.route("/<username>", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def home(username):
    print('here')
    if (str(request.form.get('signout')) == 'true'):
        print('logout')
        logout_user()
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    return render_template('home.html')
```

Here is the console upon logging in a user 'a'

```
Serving Flask app "models" (lazy loading)

Environment: production

WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.

Use a production WSGI server instead.

Debug mode: off

Running on http://127.0.0.1:8080/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)

127.0.0.1 - - [20/Nov/2018 10:11:45] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -

127.0.0.1 - - [20/Nov/2018 10:11:45] "GET /static/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -

127.0.0.1 - - [20/Nov/2018 10:11:45] "GET /static/scripts/jsx/signin.bundle.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -

127.0.0.1 - - [20/Nov/2018 10:11:46] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 401 -

this redirect doesnt work

127.0.0.1 - - [20/Nov/2018 10:11:49] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 302 -

here

127.0.0.1 - - [20/Nov/2018 10:11:50] "GET /a HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Comment: What module you are using for `login_user`?

Comment: It is the built in login_user function from flask.login DarkSuniuM. I know that it is working correctly as current_user.is_authenticated = True and in the rest of my functions, it knows who current_user is.

Comment: Check if it redirects and again redirects to the same page, you can check using your browser's Developer console/Inspect element, or you can use a simple print statement in your home view

Comment: I have editted my code with print statements. It was as you suspected, but why doesn't home.html render if it makes it into the home view?

Comment: Its weird, why debug mode is off!? always turning debug mode on in development process gives you more information about the problems u have, Its weird because after first redirect, it didn't redirected you to `index` again, also you are using `login_required` decorator, if there was any problem with authentication it would not print `here`

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have provided more information. I found out that the issue was with a POST request from an ajax call from my React front end. I found the answer her https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48015074/flask-render-template-doesnt-work-on-ajax-post Thank you for your help